# XML Query treating alias as DB

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Running this which picks up info into the RICHTEST table between the macs-mac tags:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].RichTest
SELECT doc.col.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') 
FROM @RichTests.nodes('/macs/mac') AS doc(col) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [RichTest] WHERE [Name] = doc.col.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
```

Getting this:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Database 'Doc' cannot be opened because it is offline.

Notes that When this is run in SSMS, it fails with DB 'Doc' error outlined above. And when running the following query:

```
Select @@version
```

It returns

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5538.0 (X64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end. Otherwise it works OK on SQL Server 2008R2 and SQL 2016 SSMS. Try this:

```
SELECT doc.col.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') 
    FROM @RichTests.nodes('/macs/mac') AS doc(col) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [RichTest] WHERE [Name] = doc.col.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'));
```

If you are still getting errors try patching your SSMS (or install a newer version). Note also that there is a SP4 for SQL Server 2008, but I doubt that's the problem. More likely your SSMS is RTM... Click help, about in SSMS to see your client version.